# android: is there a way to remove a string from shared preferences by its value instead of its key?

Tags: android, preferences, shared

Pretty much what the title says.

I have got a checkbox which on checked puts a string into shared prefs, and when unchecked should remove that same string.

I wanted to use the editor.remove but it asks for a key and not a string value and I can't seem to figure it out... the id would be: **`"recept" + (fav_popis.getInt("brojanje", 0) + 1)`** but that doesn't work between the strings are later used to create a listview!

```
editor.putInt("brojanje", fav_popis.getInt("brojanje", 0) + 1);

editor.putString("recept" + (fav_popis.getInt("brojanje", 0) + 1), s_product);
```

any help appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If you have different values, you must have different keys. Why dont you use values as prefix or suffix of your keys?

Comment: ok, i will try that out right now. 
im not quite sure what you mean :/ i tried to use my values as prefix and my list wasnt populated at all. i switched "recept" with s_product
is my logic wrong? or am i missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

User your checkbox text as keys of your shared preference file.

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(name, mode);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    String key = checkbox.getText();

    if(checkbox.isChecked()) {
        editor.putString(key, null);
    } else {
        editor.remove(key);
    }
    editor.commit();

    // if you want to get all the list of checkboxes checked to show in listview
    Set<String> keys = prefs.getAll().keySet();
    for(String key : keys) {
        Log.d(TAG, key);
    }
```